# Faz diferença usar LONGTEXT ao invés de VARCHAR(255)

Tags: banco-de-dados, varchar

Eu gostaria de saber se eu usar LONGTEXT ao invés de VARCHAR(255) causaria mais "lag", qual teria uma vantagem maior ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, faz diferença.

Esses dois tipos de dados são armazenados de formas diferente no banco de dados e tem funcionamentos diferentes. Por exemplo, você consegue indexar uma coluna do tipo `VARCHAR`, mas não pode indexar uma coluna do tipo `TEXT` ou `LONGTEXT`

Só use `LONGTEXT` se for para armazenar uma granda quantidade de texto nessa coluna (ela pode armazenar até 4GB). Do contrário, para informações textuais mais simples, prefira `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Vamos dizer que eu vá guardar o nome de arquivos, sendo que eu não saiba o tamanho desse nome, me recomenda usar qual ??

Comment: @LucasCarezia `VARCHAR(255)` é suficiente nesse caso.